# Returning strings from Delphi dll to C#

Tags: c#, delphi, interop

I have a delphi dll I want to return strings to a C# API.

I am using Delphi 11, and .NET 7

I have asked a similar question before, which I got to work, with sending a buffer to delphi which got filled and returned as an `out` param.

Now I need the function to return a string of unknown length, and I am struggling getting it to work.

Here is a small sample that shows the errors:

Delphi:

```pascal
library Project1;
uses
  Sharemem;

{$R *.res}

function TestWide(aInput: WideString): WideString;
begin
  result := aInput;
end;

function TestPChar(aInput: PChar): PChar;
begin
  result := aInput;
end;

function TestString(aInput: string): string;
begin
  result := aInput;
end;

exports
  TestWide, TestPChar, TestString;

begin
end.
```

C#: (The specific `DllImport` attributes might look random because I've tried all combinations)

```cs
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

internal class Program
{
        [DllImport("Project1.dll", EntryPoint = "TestWide", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, BestFitMapping = true)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)]
        public static extern string TestWide([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)] string input);

        [DllImport("Project1.dll", EntryPoint = "TestPChar", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
        public static extern string TestPChar([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string input);

        [DllImport("Project1.dll", EntryPoint = "TestString", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)]
        public static extern string TestString([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)] string input);

    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Press key to test...");
            Console.WriteLine("W for WideString");
            Console.WriteLine("P for PChar");
            Console.WriteLine("S for String");

            var key = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;
            try
            {
                switch (key)
                {
                    case 'w':
                        Console.WriteLine(TestWide("Wide")); //Runtime error 203 at address
                        break;
                    case 'p':
                        Console.WriteLine(TestPChar("Pchar")); //Another -big number exit code
                        break;
                    case 's':
                        TestString("str");  //System.AccessViolation
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Can someone please point me in the correct direction.

Comment: I don't expect the "string" type to work as that is a Delphi internal type. Can't be done, convert to widestring or pass as pointer.   It is also not clear which delphi version you use. If you use D2009+, a pchar is a pwidechar and thus a lpwstr.

Comment: Updated question with version and tried it out to no avail.

Comment: Declare them stdcall. Default is register, which is a variant (but not compatible) of fastcall iirc.

Comment: Still - but it throws an access violation as well now

Comment: Some WinAPI does the following: if the buffer allocated by the calling program and passed to the DLL function is to small, the integer/cardinal/int64 return value indicates the needed size of the buffer to return the complate data. So it's not unusual to call the function twice and adust the buffer size in between!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried all other answers but got it to work like this:

```
function TestWide(text: PWideChar): PWideChar
begin
  //DoStuff
end;

procedure DisposeStr(text: PWideChar);
begin
  StrDispose(text);
end;
```

C# call:

```
[LibraryImport("MyDll.dll", EntryPoint = "TestWide", StringMarshalling = StringMarshalling.Utf16)]
[UnmanagedCallConv(CallConvs = new Type[] { typeof(System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallConvStdcall) })]
private static partial IntPtr TestWide(string parameters);

[LibraryImport("MyDll.dll", EntryPoint = "DisposeStr")]
[UnmanagedCallConv(CallConvs = new Type[] { typeof(System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallConvStdcall) })]
private static partial void DisposeStr(IntPtr str);

public static void Test()
{
        IntPtr widePtr = TestWide("TextMessage");
        string? wideStr = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(widePtr);
        DisposeStr(widePtr);
}
```

It takes a little more management than I would like, but could not get it to work otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Between C# and Delphi, the easiest is to use `WideString/BSTR` for such a library.

```
function TestWide(const aInput: WideString): WideString; stdcall;
begin
  result := aInput;
end;
```

The benefits of `WideString/BSTR` is that they are known by both sides as native types, so both C# and Delphi will properly manage their memory. And they are also UTF-16 encoded, so it is perfect for Delphi 11, which also uses UTF-16 encoding.

Of course, there will be a conversion betwen `WideString` and `UnicodeString` but it won't hurt, and will be fast enough, especially on modern Windows. The memory will be properly handled, anyway: better safe than sorry.

But do not forget to use `stdcall` calling convention on Win32 - not needed on Win64.

And perhaps add a `const` to the parameter, so that there won't be any local copy within the implementing function. No need to have a double memory allocation for no benefit.

Last but not least, you don't need the `sharemem` unit, because you rely  on `WideString/BSTR` which uses Windows heap, not Delphi heap.